# What do you think about teaching Standard Model in school?

Tags: particle-physics, education

Here is a scan from an old Soviet textbook for school children: [image: http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/11/0129/h_1296295703_dda36c65eb.png]

It shows the table of quarks and antiquarks of different generations, colours, spins.
The book also includes similar tables of gluons and their interactions with quarks and between themselves.
They all are coded in this fancy cake-shape code.

The standard model table includes Z and W-bosons, gluons as well as graviton and gravitino.

What do you think about such manner of teaching physics and in general, what do you think about appropriateness of teaching Standard Model in junior school?

Some other images from the book (quark-gluon interactions, hadron decay):

[image: quarks-gluon interaction][image: decay of hadrons]

Illustration in a chapter about quantum parity:

[image: quantum parity]

Tha book has chapters about quantum chromodynamics, spontaneous symmetry breaking, quantum parity and so on.

Comment: This is just lovely!

Comment: This really seems to be more of a discussion than a question - it isn't looking for an answer, it's just collecting opinions, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: Still, it is interesting information :)

Answer (score 4):

Of course, we don't know the age of the soviet schoolchildren here but I think we can be confident that they wouldn't have the background to understand the quark model. So it's just sterile dogma - empty facts for memorisation.

The crucial point which distinguishes physics, and science in general is that it's experimental. The theory is not taken on trust or authority, in the end it has passed experimental tests. This is the critical insight that school students need to absorb, through doing experiments and seeing how the theory they're taught is anchored in practical experience. Even future theorists need to understand that lesson.

If there is a way to introduce 20th century ideas such as QM and RT in such a way at school level I applaud it, but based on the experience of TV popular science I'm sadly skeptical.

Comment: When you learned that Earth is round did you perform the measurement? And what about Earth's core being liquid? And millions of other facts? It's enough that the children are taught the right facts, they don't need to understand why they are true (because to understand everything would take few full human lives dedicated to science anyway...). So I think it's great to teach Standard Model along biology, chemistry and all the other knowledge.

Comment: You don't of course have to do all the experiments yourself (where did I say that?). The point is to understand that the experiments *were* done, or could have been done in principle. Many school children do in fact learn in school how experimentally the earth was shown to be spherical.

Comment: Some experimenting is ok, it may be attractive to juniors. In general, junior school is not to train future physics cracks. Physics in school is one contribution to understand the world and to learn of one way to gain insight into nature. Analog can be said on Math, Latin.....

Comment: @Nigel: yes, but how does the "experiments were done" point differ from anything else that is taught at school? In other words, what's so special about Standard Model in comparison with, say composition of DNA?

Comment: I think that's a very interesting point: experiments are "theory-laden". An electron diffraction experiment is a startling confirmation of wave-particle duality (and quantitatively of wave mechanics) if you have already internalised the concepts of electrons-as-particles, crystal lattices, wave diffraction and how quite sophisticated pieces of apparatus actually work. It's the cumulative nature of experimental as well as theoretical physics which impedes take-up of sophisticated theories such as the SM in early schooling. DNA structure may be conceptually closer to experience.

Comment: @Marek Is composition of DNA taught in junior school? I though it was about colours, letters, elementary math and grammar,, and recognition of objects (so a bit of botanic, geography and even geology if you wish). This is, experiments that can be understood (and even done) at this level.

Comment: @Marek actually I thik you should delete and edit again your first comment, it is impossible that you really were pretending to say that "they don't need to understand why they are true ". If you address education with this rule, you actually teach such rule as a metaconcept: children learn that they dont need to understand why the facts -any facts they are told with authority enough- are true.

Comment: @Nigel: I don't agree. How is DNA close to experience? How is a concept of an atom, for that matter close to experience? And yet, every little child now understands atomic hypothesis. It's just about teaching the concepts early and letting the children get used to them. I don't think you need to know how to compute Bhabha scattering or understand representations of Poincaré group to get a little grasp how particle physics works.

Comment: @arivero: I won't delete that comment because I meant it the way it is written. It's good if you know why something is true, but just knowing that it is true is the first step towards knowledge. Try to be honest and let me know how much of what you know is true do you really understand? I doubt it's even a percent ;) I don't have to understand quantum gravity to know that Earth revolves around the Sun and will do so again tomorrow. And similarly for every other fact of life.

Comment: @Marek With the definition of @Nigel, "understand that the experiments were done, or could have been done in principle.", I say above 90% for sure. Perhaps 70% if you ask also to propose a concrete experimental setup. Still, I can agree with your point with a slightly twist: knowing that something is false. Here the problem in elementary school can be to teach the difference between plain falsity, and approximation.

Comment: @Marek, by the way your example with the Sun is a good one: it can be learn by experiment that the sun appears every morning. You dont need to believe it. Perhaps the point is that for every answer, in good practice of science -and teaching- other question arrives :-D Why does it appear? How does it appear? And so you introduce astronomical observation...

Comment: @arivero: you are either brilliant or hypocrite :) But I very much doubt you could propose experimental setup for most of the facts from chemistry, biology or other applied sciences. As for the "experiments were done", sure, you can teach that kids too. But I don't see how plain believing something and believing it while also knowing that it can be reproduced but also that you won't ever conduct such an experiment yourself in your life even if you could :)

Comment: @arivero: well, the point about Sun is that you don't need to understand fundamental physics, or even general relativity or even Newtonian gravity to know it's true. It won't help you in any way. And while you can see Sun for yourself, you can't see your DNA usually but it's still useful to learn basic facts about it. Even though you won't understand the precise chemical and quantum mechanical processes that underlie it.

Comment: I agree fully with this answer. It's just facts with little meaning. To be quite honest, I'm currently studying a course on nuclear and particle physics as a final year undergraduate, and not having done QFT, a lot of the background is still missing!

Comment: @Marek, the issue here is what constitutes "understanding". It's been a discussion in Artificial Intelligence (knowledge representation) too. Suppose you teach a six year old kid *E = mc^2*. They could memorise it and perhaps answer a simple exam question which required them to reproduce it but would we say they understood what it meant (without the network of concepts which anchor the equation to prior understood content)? At *some level*, by analogies, you could *say* you could teach almost anything to any age-level. I suspect the OP meant "teach with sufficient understanding" though.

Comment: @Marek You didn't asked absolute quantity of knowledge :-D I have forgotten, or never learnt, a lot of chemistry etc.  As for the difference, I'd say that knowing the arguments for the experiment imply the use of logic and reason at a deeper level than plain belief. Note that belief by itself asks for very few logic effort. You can easily find people who can believe contradictory narrations. Belief + Logic is an advance, but that is Thomas Aquinas :-( And adding gedankenexperiments, we get Lucretius or so, advanced but not very accurate (still, good ideas for primary shool :-DDD)

Comment: @Nigel: well, you obviously can't teach equations if the child doesn't yet know the mathematical formalism :) But you can explain that there are electrons and photons and that they can be absorbed and emitted and you can explain lots of basic processes, etc. These are such elementary things that even 10-yo could understand them. And yes, I know of people who read popular books such as Hawking's and Greene's at 10-yo and got a good grasp on the fundamentals of our world despite being at least another 10 years away from real math and physics.

Comment: @arivero: no, I was just talking about the things you already know. So you are saying that you only know things you really understand? That's quite impressive. Most of the things I know (especially outside physics) are just plain belief. But I know I could google up why they are true and that's enough for me.

Comment: @Marek besides google (and yep I google a lot) I rely on interdiscipline discussion a lot, plus girlfriends outside physics :-D. But now you name it, the existence of google + wikipedia as a substitute of library is important and teachers should address how it incorporates to the teaching in elementary levels. Perhaps all the point to go beyond belief is to know that you could either to find someone near to ask or to find a library to read for confirmation. Still, plainly asking authority smells a bit clerical to me. Priest and popes, arggg.

Comment: @arivero: well, people in physics and math are lucky because they can usually derive and check things for themselves. But for everything else you need priests and popes. It reminds me of a quote actually: "New York has gone. No reaction. He'd never seriously believed it existed anyway." :)

Comment: @Marek Still, perhaps specialized knowledge is the way to go. Plus an ability to use and manipulate objects in a formal way. My own mood of learning worked only until graduate, but failed in posgraduate courses (1983, not even decent textbooks in the library, not Weinberg nor Peskin) so I can not praise it. And looking back to elementary school, yes, we used V=IR 'formally' without understanding it, but at least with the ethernal promise of it being explained "the next year".

Answer (score 3):

First of all I should say that I find this particular way of presenting quarks rather unfortunate. Not only it delivers very little physics information, but it's even quite misleading (I mean those fancy shapes). On the other hand, I do believe that teaching some modern physics at high school is extremely important. Of course the students do not have the background to understand how quantum mechanics works - maybe apart from the semiclassical approaches such as Bohr quantization which should be avoided at any cost since it only leads to confusion. Of course, as Nigel Seel pointed out, the students should absorb the theory-experiment relation and understand their role. However, an equally (and sometimes even more) important part of the education of possible future scientists is a motivation for choosing a research career. Thus, the students should get in touch with modern physics as soon as possible so that they are not discouraged by the fact that they have to go through many years of study of theoretical background that was developed more than 100 years ago. In fact, one can get their hands on and have a lot of fun with physics without really understanding deeply the underlying theory. I expect objections that classical mechanics and all the other standard high school material can also be made interesting, yet I think that for the sake of motivation, nothing can beat showing the students a (though tiny) part of the actual current research.

Comment: Exactly, it's disheartening that even at university level the exciting topics that encouraged people to study physics in the first place are sometimes postponed until later years of the course. +1.

Comment: @Nigel: I disagree, sorry :) It's nice that people are excited about doing physics but you can't really study exciting topics before you mastered all the underlying "boring" physics and mathematics and that simply takes time. I know what I am talking about; I wanted to study strings since high school and was occasionally trying ever since then but it was only after going through lots of math courses and QFT and GR that trying to learn them became worthwhile.

Comment: When I did physics at university - plenty of years ago now :-( they did neither QM or SR in the first year. I was *not* impressed.

Comment: @Marek: There is a lot of physics besides string theory one can do without having a deep knowledge of quantum field theory and all that. For example, a lot of very exciting experimental work in the field of the ultracold atomic gases can de done with just moderate knowledge of quantum mechanics. Moreover, one should really not insist on mastering all the necessary background before starting any research. In this respect, the essay "Scientist: Four golden lessons" by Steven Weinberg is quite encouraging.

Comment: @Tomáš: well, I must admit I have a very little knowledge of experimental physics so it might be possible. But in theoretical physics I don't think one can start a reasonable research before finishing at least undergraduate studies. Sure, sometimes you can learn while researching. But it only works if the stuff you have to learn is not too hard or there is not too much of it. So you definitely need a good background before attempting anything non-trivial.

Comment: @Nigel: well, neither did they do it in my first year. But still, even in second year lots of people were still having trouble with tensor calculus and Hilbert spaces (not to mention functional analysis or any group theory which were omitted altogether). So the level of those SR and QM was still too low for my liking. I can't (and don't want to) imagine what it would look like in first year... Personally I prefer being first taught math so I can appreciate the physics better. Physical hand-waving with no math content -- undergraduate stuff in other words -- just doesn't cut it :)

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with @Sigel arguments, that the substructure of matter should be delayed until the appropiate age for understanding its process of discovery, I think that it should exist an appropiate way to answer the question *if the kids ask it*.

We can not just answer "*turtles until the end*" not to appeal to mistery or legend. And while we can explain that the technical details of the argument will be addressed at later ages, we must still stress that they can be addressed by the use of reason and experiment.

This implies that the teacher could need some support material in order to focus on how to answer this question -substructure of matter- if it is asked. The booklet above contains some good ideas, but it should never be a main teaching material, it should be support material.

Answer (score 1):

It's chronologically impossible to write about M-theory in Soviet textbook. The good thing is when bright kids have access to information and can ask knowledgeable people the questions.

Comment: Indeed. But there is a chapter about the grand unified theory.